# Angular website crashes when scrolling fast

Tags: angular, firebase, web, scroll, crash

So, I have created a website with the latest version of Angular.
I have it hosted through Firebase.

The issue is that the website crashes on scroll.
I go to https://torpalangan.se and everything loads in fine. But as soon as I start scrolling it crashes due to “an issue occurred several times on [https://torpalangan.se/”](https://torpalangan.se/%E2%80%9D).

I can use the menu and go to another page and scroll around, go back to start page again, start scrolling, and CRASH!

Sometimes I can scroll slowly down on the start page.

It also crashes when tapping the clock (on iPhone) to scroll to top.

So it seems like when the startpage is scrolled too fast it crashes. And again, crashes only happens on the startpage.

I have several other websites setup the exact same way, but never had this problem before.

**UPDATE: Only an issue on iPhone!**

Here’s a video from my iPhone: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVomZ9xQxRVeh9JUtsVjlQTJ-FZFdPOa/view?usp=drivesdk

I’m looking in the console, but I can’t find any errors that would explain this behavior.

Comment: Impossible to answer this question without seeing the repo, but my first thought is to audit any subscriptions to router events for memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tanner. Here is the repo: https://github.com/Philipdev95/torpalangan2

Comment: I get a 404 at that link. Perhaps it is private?